# Menu items not clickable

Tags: menus, css

Our website is chinesealpha.com

All of a sudden, our menu items are non-clickable.

Does any of you have an idea how to resolve this?
I tried re-configuring the menu list, doens't work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to include the CSS code:

```
.td-header-menu-social {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is off to a nice start. Please consider explaining how and why this solves the problem so others can learn from it. Check the [guide to answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further advice.